# Python PieChart (is it possible to do CallOut labels)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart, plot-annotations

Is there any examples of doing CallOut Labels with Python, Matplotlib etc

[image]
[Image source](http://nusoft.fnal.gov/nova/commissioning/ActiveChannelbyCoating/ChartDirector/doc/cdpydoc/images/legendpie2.png)

Something like above with a line and the label pointing from outside the pie chart.. cannot see any possible examples of it being done with Mathplotlib.... can this be done with Python??

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I am however struggling to apply the following to my code...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use matplotlib **[annotations](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html)** to create text labels and annotation lines.

#### Manual labeling

Here is an example, where the labels are positionned manually in Data coordinates, i.e. the center of the pie is (0,0) coordinate.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
total = [13,87]
plt.title('How to spot intellectuals on TV')
plt.gca().axis("equal")
pie = plt.pie(total, startangle=93)
labels = ["1. They say sophisticated things", "2. They sit in front of a bookshelf"]

bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",connectionstyle="angle,angleA=0,angleB=90")
kw = dict(xycoords='data',textcoords='data',
          arrowprops=arrowprops, bbox=bbox_props, zorder=0)
plt.gca().annotate("2", xy=(0, 0), xytext=( 1.1, -0.8), **kw )
plt.gca().annotate("1", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(-1.1,  0.8), **kw )

plt.legend(pie[0],labels, loc="center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,-0.1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Automatic labeling:

We can use the angles of the wedges to automatically create labels at the positions, which are suitable.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
total = [12,15,12,13,16]
plt.title('My repair strategies')
plt.gca().axis("equal")
patches, texts = pie = plt.pie(total, startangle=5)
labels = ["1. roaring at it", 
          "2. hitting it",
          "3. using superglue",
          "4. using duct tape",
          "5. dismantling it, then ditch it"]

bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",connectionstyle="angle,angleA=0,angleB=90")
kw = dict(xycoords='data',textcoords='data',arrowprops=arrowprops, 
          bbox=bbox_props, zorder=0, va="center")

for i, p in enumerate(patches):
    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1)/2.+p.theta1
    y = np.sin(ang/180.*np.pi)
    x = 1.35*np.sign(np.cos(ang/180.*np.pi))
    plt.gca().annotate(str(1+i), xy=(0, 0), xytext=( x, y), **kw )

plt.legend(pie[0],labels, loc="center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,-0.2))
plt.show()
```

[image]