# Python Matplotlib Callouts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've asked the below question before but I am having a hard time trying to implement the example provided in my code to get the labels in a 'callout' or 'Annotation' so the text does not overlap. I am hoping someone would be able to assist me. Here is my previous question.
[Python PieChart (is it possible to do CallOut labels)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349004/python-piechart-is-it-possible-to-do-callout-labels)

Here is my code so far:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import os
#Connect to Database
mypath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
conn =sqlite3.connect('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\db\DeviceRegister.sqlite3')
#Connect to the sqlite3 database
cursor = conn.cursor()  # Set cursor as the cursor for plus.sqlite
#SQL Query
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT devices.id AS id, macs.address AS mac,     oses.name AS os, browsers.name AS browser FROM devices JOIN macs ON devices.mac = macs.id JOIN oses ON devices.os = oses.id JOIN browsers ON devices.browser = browsers.id", conn)
df_browsers = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['mac','browser'])
#Get Data
counterbrowsers = Counter(df_browsers['browser'])
browser_names = counterbrowsers.keys()
browser_counts = counterbrowsers.values()
#Pie Chart
plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.3))
labels, values = zip(*sorted(counterbrowsers.items(), key=lambda x:   x[1])) #Counteros is the Dictionary-like object we are trying to sort.  
This 'zip' solves the problem of sorting each of them independently.
This   
will sort as pairs, by value.
labels = ['{0} : {1:1}'.format(i,j) for i,j in zip(labels, values)]
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'lightskyblue',  'lightcoral','#008DB8','#00AAAA','#001CF0','#00FF80','c','m','r','b','#1970','#0038E2','#0055D4','#0071C6','#00E28E', '#00C69C']
explode = list()
for k in labels:
explode.append(0.1)
def make_autopct(values):
def my_autopct(pct):
total = sum(values)
        val=int(round(pct*total/100))
    return '{p:.0f}%  ({v:d})'.format(p=pct,v=val)
return my_autopct
pie = plt.pie(values, labels=labels, explode=explode, colors=colors, shadow=True, startangle=90, autopct=make_autopct(values))  
plt.suptitle('Browsers Analytics', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':7})
plt.legend(labels, loc="lower right")
plt.axis('equal') # Set aspect ratio to be equal so that pie is drawn as a circle, # View the plot drop above
plt.savefig(mypath + 'piebrowsers.png')
```

Comment: first thing: Beautify your code, it's easier to start out by going cell by cell in a jupyter notebook, then adjusting your problem from there.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve], e.g. by using a DataFrame which you have created inside the code, such that the issue can be reproduced. You should also explain more in detail what the actual issue is. Providing an image of the issue is also helpful; you can then use the image to explain what you don't like about your code.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the reply. I want to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43349004/6643943 but instead of numbers have my labels so in this case browser_names, does that make sense?

Comment: It sure makes sense. But it's hard to see where your problem lies or what the problem is in the first place. The answer uses annotations to get the labels in a box with a line pointing towards the pie. In the code from the question you have the labels inside the call to `pie`. So you'd need to adapt your code to the way I was doing it in the linked answer. Again, if you have a specific problem, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use `plt.legend(loc='location you want it to appear')`

i.e. `plt.legend(loc='upper left')`

'best'         : 0, 
'upper right'  : 1,
'upper left'   : 2,
'lower left'   : 3,
'lower right'  : 4,
'right'        : 5,
'center left'  : 6,
'center right' : 7,
'lower center' : 8,
'upper center' : 9,
'center'       : 10,

For more information.
http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/legend_api.html

Comment: I want the labels on the pie chart, so a line to the labels so they don't overlap, in VBA this was called a 'callout'... annotation by the looks of it in matplotlib???

Comment: That only moved the legend.

Comment: @iHaag You got this kind of anwer because you did not explain your problem well and you don't provide a [mcve]. So the answerer had to somehow guess what your problem might be.

Comment: @importanceofbeingernest i'm trying to do the example you provided in my previous question in the link but have my labels as the callouts so it's clearer to see the labels as they overlap